# Setting Unit Defaults?

Tags: delphi, ide

Not a programming question as such, but..

..Is there a way from the Delphi IDE to define information that will be applied to newly created Units?

For example, suppose I wanted each new Unit to add some commented information to the top, like so:

[image]

I like to add such information to Units so that anyone else who may need access to it has some brief information. Obviously I am not expecting the IDE to fill in the Overview information.

I noticed some OpenSource Components include the License Information at the top of Units, I assume they were just Copy and Pasted in there, but wouldnt it be handy if there was a way to Automate such IDE behaviour?

Additionally, I have a few external Units added to my Library Path, which I add to the Uses Clause of a Form/Unit when needed. There is one paticular Unit I always find myself using, It would also be handy to Automatically include X Unit to the Uses Clause of New Units.

Is there a trick to doing something like this, or should Copy and Paste be enough?

Thanks.

Comment: You accepted the first answer very fast. It might be worth to let others some time to answer as well. This will give you more feedback on your question than a single answer does. Oh, and +1 for the question.

Comment: @Smasher +1 I agree, don't accept the first answer after a few minutes, let the question gestate some

Comment: ok, I unanswered it. I accepted it so fast because I believed David answered what I already thought, I asked to make sure if there was a possible way,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to stick to copy/paste.  If there was a slick way to do this then every single Delphi programmer on the planet would have used it to turn this

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

into this

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  end;
```

Comment: True I guess. I always wondered is there a way to remove the Private/Public declarations and add them yourself when needed - guess you answered that too. thanks.

Comment: I personally would prefer Embarcadero not to add such a feature. Adding a new unit is not something that is done very frequently. I'd rather they spent their resources on real pain points in the product.

Comment: @David: Adding a new unit not done very frequently? Interesting. I guess that's why we have added an "add new unit" to our own expert? Admittedly it serves to add it to source control as well (so we don't forget that and break a build), but it also adds headers, a standard uses clause, our include file, that kinda stuff... Pretty handy even if we use it only like ... oh, dunno depends on what I am working on...

Comment: @Marjan: agreed. That probably depends on the project and how "established" the project already is, but I am creating new units very frequently.

Comment: @Marjan The infrequency is probably what makes your expert useful. If you did it 10 times a day you'd not forget all the little steps that have to be done!!

Comment: @Smasher @Marjan On the other hand, perhaps not everyone's work patterns are the same as mine!!

Comment: @David: Well yes, that is the reason for its existence... :-) Though there are times when I am adding units like crazy, months can go by without adding a single one!

Comment: @David - You can get rid of the `private`/`public` sections for good by modifying 'delphivclide###.bpl', 'VCLIDECMD' resource in RCDATA. Templates are separated by a `|`. A new form's template is the 4th one for D2007.

Comment: @Sertac Not sure I'd want to change it that way!

Comment: @David - Ethical? Or because a possible update will skip the file? FTR I haven't done it myself till today, it doesn't bother me much.

Comment: @sertac update is the issue. Doesn't bother me enough   anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider using a [`Delphi live template`](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Live_Templates) too.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to use [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) or [CNPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en). These are great IDE enhancements and they can be used to paste configurable pieces of code using a simple hotkey. In GExperts this is called **Code Librarian**, CNPack has a similar feature. They contain a lot of other valuable tools so it might be worth to check these out.

Comment: +1, I have used GExperts before but found it rather buggy (at least the rename components tool was). I should look at the extra tools they provide.

Comment: @Craig, go directly to CnPack, they are superior now. The only drawback (at least for me) is comments in Chinese.

Comment: will try that out. I feared some of it may be chinese looking from the site.

Answer (score 1):

Like Marjan already mentioned using an expert for a new custom unit, you can also make an IDE expert rewriting Delphi's default unit code for maximum customizability. But since this answer likely implies the most required work of all, I shall not go in detail or sample code. It's just a possibility.

Comment: Actually this is only correct approach, to implement IOTARepositoryWizard and IOTAModuleCreator.

Comment: @Downvoter That suggest you would replace the unit? I think I would use IOTAIDENotifier to respond to opening the new Form, and IOTASourceEditor to modify the source.

Comment: for 2nd part of question "create a custom unit from the template", yes. Object Repository allows adding projects or forms with easy, but not units (w/o hack to lift the restriction). Thus, fully fledged solution for that task will be IOTARepositoryWizard with customised IOTAModuleCreator.